# Gnuplot customized y-ticks

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I am using the attached script to make a 3D image with colorbar.
But I do not know how to change the y axis in a way that 2/3 of it shows [0,250] and the rest 1/3 shows [250:400]. In this way, I want to have a zoom in the lower y values. I tried broken axis but it did not work with splot and it is not what I am trying to have. I was thinking about multiplot option 2x1 rowfirst, with additional space for the first row but I cannot do it.

Anyone can help me please?

script:

```
    set term postscript eps enhanced color fontscale 2.0
    set output '|ps2pdf - surf.pdf'
    set bar 1.000000 front
    set border 4095 front lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
    set style circle radius graph 0.02, first 0.00000, 0.00000
    set style ellipse size graph 0.05, 0.03, first 0.00000 angle 0 units xy
    set style textbox transparent margins  1.0,  1.0 border
    set logscale cb
    set format cb "%2.0t{/Symbol\264}10^{%L}"
    set encoding utf8
    set view map scale 1
    set samples 50, 50
    set isosamples 50, 50
    unset surface
    set style data pm3d
    set style function pm3d
    set xyplane relative 0
    unset paxis 1 tics
    unset paxis 2 tics
    unset paxis 3 tics
    unset paxis 4 tics
    unset paxis 5 tics
    unset paxis 6 tics
    unset paxis 7 tics
    ##set title "colour map, using default rgbformulae 7,5,15 ... traditional pm3d (black-blue-red-yellow)"
    set xlabel "Energy (eV)"
    set xrange [ 2490 : 2500 ] noreverse nowriteback
    set ylabel "Time (fs)"
    set yrange [ 0.0 : 400 ] noreverse nowriteback
    set xtics 2490,2,2500
    set paxis 1 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 2 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 3 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 4 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 5 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 6 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set paxis 7 range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
    set pm3d implicit at b
    set colorbox vertical origin screen 0.9, 0.2, 0 size screen 0.05, 0.6, 0 front  noinvert bdefault
    splot 'surface.txt' u 2:1:3 notitle
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you asking only about the y-axis tick labels and not about rescaling the axis itself, then here is an example of finely spaced labels spanning [0:250] combined with two extra labels at 300 and 400.

```
set ytics 0, 10, 250
set ytics add (300, 400)
```

Comment: It is not only about putting desire y-tick labels. It is about having bottom part larger than top part in y-axis.